# Using socket io instance out side the app.js

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I want to be able to import the socket instance without needing to re define it in my controller

my structure gose like
app => routs => controller

```
async getAllUserConnections (req,res){
        const uid = {
           id:  req.user.id
        }
        try {
            const data= await 
            db.userConnections.findAll({
                where :{
                    resiver_user_id :uid.id
                },
                 include: [{
                      model:db.user
                  }]
                
            });
        io.of('/not').on("connection",function(){
            console.log("Connected");

        })
            if (data.length == 0) 
            return res.send('there is no Data to get');
            return res.send(data)
        }catch(error){
            return res.send(error)
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for the issue

create socket.js

in socket.js

```
 const socketio =require('socket.io');
    var io = null;
    exports.io = function () {
      return io;
    };
    exports.initialize = function(server) {
      return io = socketio(server);
    };
```

now in your app.js

```
var io = require('./socket').initialize(server);
```

and finally anywhere in your app

```
const io = require("../socket").io(); 

       io.of("/not").use(socketToken)
        io.of("/not").on('connection',function(socket){
        socket.emit("hi","you are  good to go ")});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use app.locals in express to share variables globally in the app

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const server = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);

// Store the io instance in app.locals
app.locals.io = io;

// Example HTTP request handler that uses the io instance
app.get('/message', (req, res) => {
  const message = req.query.message;

  // Use the io instance to emit a message to all connected clients
  app.locals.io.emit('newMessage', message);
  res.send('Message sent');
});
```

Or you can use "req.app.locals.io" in your controller file when you dont have access to app instance